# Plotting multiple line graphs from a single datasheet

Tags: r, ggplot2

looking for some help plotting some data. I have a data sheet containing growth information in the following format:

```
    Sample  Treatment  TimePoint FinalConc
    1      Dark        T1         132
    1      Dark        T2         159
    1      Dark        T3         170
    1      Light       T1         100
    ....
    42     Dark        T1         51
    42     Dark        T2         49
    42     Dark        T3         30
    42     Light       T1         25
    42     Light       T2         31
    42     Light       T3         84
```

I am trying to generate a plot that looks like this one:

[image: R Photo]

Where each graph has the Light and Dark treatment plotted (instead of male and female).

I tried the following:

```
    datafile <- read.table("counts.txt",sep="\t",header = TRUE)
    ggplot(data = datafile, aes(x = TimePoint, y = FinalConcentration, group = Sample)) + facet_wrap(~Sample)
```

but when it plotted it there were 42 graphs but all of them were empty. I am new to using R so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to add a `geom_line`, and maybe make the time points integers instead of character.

Comment: I got it working now thanks to this suggestion!